# PHP - Laravel 4- Resource Controller Missing Method

Tags: php, rest, laravel, laravel-4

There's a problem with Laravel 4, since i have updated it. I have no idea why its calling a missing Method error, where there's no problem with my resource nor my routes

```
     * Handle calls to missing methods on the controller.
 *
 * @param  array   $parameters
 * @return mixed
 */
public function missingMethod($parameters)
{
    throw new NotFoundHttpException;
}
```

It calls this when i call

```
api/user/4
```

or when i call

```
api/users/all
```

There should be no problem since i've done this in my routes

```
Route::resource('api/user','UserApiController');
Route::resource('photo','PhotoController');
```

Would anyone please do help me on this menial problem?

### EDIT

here's the actual website www.codify.ph

api calls are as follow

www.codify.ph/api/users/all?skip=0&take=10

here's the github repository (yes we're open source)
https://github.com/philippine-devnet/codify

Comment: For `GET: api/user/4`, do you have a `public function show($id)` method in your resourceful controller?

Comment: yes, i have.. i used artisan's way of generating resource controller

Comment: Have you set your root URL in your `app/config/app.php`?

Comment: sir @JanP. actually, yes i have set it already

Comment: Is `api/user/create` working ? And does it works if you use a route like `Route::get('api/user/{id}', array('uses' => 'UserApiController@show'))` ?

Comment: I only know Larvel4, I've never seen a `api/users/all`. To get all records in L4 you would use `api/users` which would call `index()` in your `UserController` from my experience. `api/users/4` would call `show($id)` in your `UserController`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually understood it already,

For Laravelists out there, you should have your routes on the following format

any route registration with

```
Route::resource("/") or Route::controller("/")
```

should be below or after any controllers and routes, for some reason the route naming ends with the /

example

```
Route::group(array('before'=>'authed', 'prefix'=>'dashboard'), function() 
{
    Route::resource('users','UserDashboardController');
    Route::resource('clients','ClientDashboardController');
    Route::controller('/', 'DashboardController');
});
```

notice that the "/" is at the very last.

Answer (score 0):

Remove

```
app/storage/meta/services.json
```